# Get context in Android?

Tags: android

I am inside a class inside my android app, how can I get the apps main context and activity?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question as is, is impossible to answer. Please provide more details on your problem. What have you tried so far? What does your code look like? Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Couldn't have given more information besides "a class"? All we could assume is that it inherits from Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a custom view: there is a paramater context which is your activity.

```
Activity activity = (Activity)context;
```

If it's a different class just send the activity in the constrctor.

Answer (score 26):

I am sure you already have the context but you don't know that it is the context:

[Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is an abstract base class a lot of classes are inherited from.

Therefore when ever the class you are writing code for is one of the following you have you context by using the `this` reference:

- ContextWrapper
- MockContext
- AbstractInputMethodService
- AccessibilityService
- AccountAuthenticatorActivity
- Activity
- ActivityGroup
- AliasActivity
- Application
- BackupAgent
- BackupAgentHelper
- ContextThemeWrapper
- ExpandableListActivity
- InputMethodService
- IntentService
- IsolatedContext
- LauncherActivity
- ListActivity
- MockApplication
- MutableContextWrapper
- NativeActivity
- PreferenceActivity
- RecognitionService
- RemoteViewsService
- RenamingDelegatingContext
- Service
- SpellCheckerService
- TabActivity
- TextToSpeechService
- VpnService
- WallpaperService

Hence you can write:

```
Context context = this;
```

or

```
Context context = (Context) this;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Robert mentioned, *Context* is an abstract class and what you have are structures:

> Context < ContextWrapper < Application
>
> Context < ContextWrapper < ContextThemeWrapper < Activity
>
> Context < ContextWrapper < ContextThemeWrapper < Activity <
>   ListActivity
>
> Context < ContextWrapper < Service
>
> Context < ContextWrapper < Service < IntentService

So, all of those classes are contexts in their own way. You can cast *Service* and *ListActivity* to *Context* if you wish. But if you look closely, some of the classes inherit theme as well. In activity or fragment, you would like theming to be applied to your views, but don't care about it elsewhere.

I explain the difference in contexts [here](http://lomza.totem-soft.com/what-is-it-about-context-in-android/).